# Radio Control DC Motor With Potentiometer

Tags: rf, dc-motor, motor-controller

I am looking to control a 12V 16A 180RPM DC motor. The package I am purchasing includes this motor, and a speed controller. [Please see this link](http://www.motiondynamics.com.au/home-brewer-special-worm-drive-motor-dc-speed-controller.html) for the exact detils.

The speed controller comes with a potentiometer for controlling the speed of the motor rotation.

I have found radio controlled remote controlled switches, [like this one](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/121273758874?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWAX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649), that suits DC motors up to 12V 30A - which would be more than enough for my motor. Button 'A' makes the motor go faster, and button 'B' makes it go slower.

My question is, can a potentiometer (dial or knob like on the wired speed controller) be put into a radio controlled remote like this? And if so, how?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The remote control you pointed to is on/off only.  (It has a relay.) It does not permit control of speed.

Comment: Perhaps you hope there's a simple way to connect a remote control receiver to the speed controller you are buying. The ad doesn't mention any suitable input -- the unit seems not designed for that purpose. It may be possible to hack a way to do it, but need a schematic to assess possibilities. You don't want to be inventing from scratch, probably want to leverage existing radio-control PWM control gear if possible. So, question is does this unit facilitate that, or is there an off-the-shelf R/C PWM controller with suitable power handling?

Comment: A pedestrian way would be to use conventional R/C driving a servo that turns the potentiometer. Definitely doable, but not as elegant as an all-electronic interface.

Answer (score 1):

Digital potentiometer may work for you:

http://www.maximintegrated.com/products/data_converters/digi-pot/

Given you want to do some soldering and designing, that is.